# Prove that $\frac{g^TB^{-1}g}{\|g\|\|B^{-1}g\|}\ge\frac{1}{c}$ if $B$ is positive definite and $\|B\|\|B^{-1}\|\le c$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, functional-analysis, optimization

I have a trouble to prove the following statement which is from a convergence theorem in optimization.

> $$\cos\theta=\frac{g^TB^{-1}g}{\|g\|\|B^{-1}g\|}\ge\frac{1}{c}$$ for any $g \in \mathbb{R}^n$, if $B$ is positive definite and $\|B\|\|B^{-1}\|\le c$, where $c\in\mathbb R$ is a positive constant.

The norm of matrix is defined this way:

> $$\|B\|=\sup_{x\ne 0}\frac{\|Bx\|}{\|x\|}$$

Thanks in advance for any tip. For more information,  this is "simple fact" used in a proof of line search convergence theorem in optimization theory. $g$ is the gradient of objective function.

Comment: How come downvote ?

Comment: I don't know the reason why someone downvoted without leaving a comment, and I don't agree since the problem seems interesting. The hint I can give you, is: the quadratic form on the numerator is the analytic description of a hyper-ellipsoid in $\mathbb R^n$, with form matrix $B$, so main axes along eigenvectors, and semiaxes length equal to the eigenvalues.

Comment: @Vexx23 Thanks for comment. I know this fact and I'll try with this. I guess I need to add a condition that $B$ is positive definite ?

Comment: Sorry I have taken it for granted thinking it was implicit, I usually come across positive definite matrices in convex problems such as identification, linear regression, optimization. Is this not the case?

Comment: @Vexx23 This should be the case, otherwise $cos\theta$ may be negative. And this is "simple fact" used in a proof of line search convergence theorem. $g$ is the gradient of the objective function.

Comment: My best guess is that your question was downvoted because you haven't included your own thoughts on the question (as in, what have you tried so far?). That seems to be a common complaint.

Comment: By rearranging the inequality, we see it is equivalent to show that
$$
g^TB^{-1}g \geq \frac 1c\|g\| \cdot \|B^{-1} g\|
$$
In other words, we want to show that
$$
g^TB^{-1}g \geq \frac 1{\|B\|\cdot \|B^{-1}\|} \cdot \|g\| \cdot \|B^{-1} g\|
$$

Comment: Notably, we can get the result
$$
g^TB^{-1}g \geq \frac{\|g\|^2}{\|B\|}
$$
fairly simply, but I don't think we can do better

Comment: @Omnomnomnom Er, I see. Then it is reasonable, but I just hadn't had any clue and had not much progress, so I didn't mention it.

Comment: @Hua I wouldnt worry about it, your question is fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By Rayleigh's theorem, we can get
$$
g^TB^{-1}g \geq \frac{\|g\|^2}{\|B\|}
$$
From there, it suffices to note
$$
\frac{\|g\|^2}{\|B\|} = \frac{\|g\| \cdot \|B^{-1}\|\|g\|}{\|B\|\cdot \|B\|^{-1}} \geq 
\frac{\|g\|\cdot \|B^{-1} g\|}{\|B\|\cdot \|B\|^{-1}} \geq 
\frac{\|g\|\cdot \|B^{-1} g\|}{c}
$$
which is the desired result.

Comment: Sorry, I still don't get the first inequality. Actually I don't know what Rayleigh's theorem is, do you mean [Rayleigh quotient](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rayleigh_quotient) ? But this is involved only Hermitian matrix. I can't find other related result but this one ...

Comment: @Hua positive definite matrices **are** Hermitian (i.e. symmetric) by the definition that I'm used to

Comment: Thanks ! I get it. By the quotient inequality, $\frac{g^TB^{-1}g}{g^Tg}\ge \lambda_{min}(B^{-1})=\frac{1}{\lambda_{max}(B)}=\frac{1}{\|B\|}$

Comment: Right. In fact, that last inequality is an equality, since $B$ is (symmetric and) positive definite.

Comment: Oh, really, I don't know this. Thanks for pointing this out.

Comment: You're welcome.  That also comes straight from a quotient inequality:
$$
\|B\|^2 = \max \frac{\|Bx\|^2}{\|x\|^2} = 
\max \frac{x^TB^TBx}{x^Tx} = \max \frac{x^TB^2x}{x^Tx} = [\lambda_{max}(B)]^2
$$